# How to give anonymous user access in a menu hook?

Tags: routes

I have a module with a menu hook that I want to give access to everyone. At first I had simply

```
function hook_menu() {
  $items['site_search'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'my_callback',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

But when I navigated to `/search`, I got a warning that I didn't have permission. I thought I had remembered somewhere along the line that I could do `'access callback' => TRUE,` in the menu hook to allow anonymous access, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Do I really have to add another function that just returns true to use as the access callback to give anonymous users access to this path?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can definitely set `'access callback' => TRUE` on the menu item and that will bypass any access checks, you don't need to implement a function that just returns `TRUE` (it would be redundant). Don't forget you need to clear the caches before changes in hook_menu will get picked up though.

Rather than just blindly returning `TRUE` though it's probably a better idea to assign a permission to the anonymous user role, or piggyback off of one that's already there (`access content` is the usual suspect for this if it fits in with your workflow). You can do that by using `'access arguments' => array('access content')` **instead of** `'access callback'` (don't use both).

Also you've missed out the `title` in your example, according to [the docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) that property is required. I doubt that's actually causing the problem though.

Just on another note, you mention that you're visiting '/search' to test this page - the path you've defined will be at '/site_search' instead.

Comment: You're right, it does work. Forgot to clear the cache :P